# Looking for enterprise web application design inspiration

Tags: website-design, gui-design, web-app, wireframe

I've checked many websites to be inspired about what the look and feel of a serious enterprise web-application should look like. But the whole I saw were designed for being used by single users and not serious corporate users. The designs I saw were mostly happy-colored, and looked like being developed by a small team of eager young passionate developers.

But what I'm looking for, are showcases of serious web apps' designs (e.g. web apps developed by large corporations) that are developed for being used by a large number of corporate uses.

Can you suggest me sources for this kind of inspiration?

Comment: This is a vague question that really isn't all that answerable. Good UX principals apply to whatever web application you might be building whether it's enterprise or not.

Comment: Sir I'm asking for inspiration sources (web sites). I accept your words about good UX principals but I'm asking for web pages that showcase enterprise apps (e.g. SAP, Oracle, VMWare,... -developed web apps)

Comment: Asking for inspiration or a list of examples of something doesn't really constitute an answerable question so isn't a good fit for this site. Is there anything *particular* you have a question about for an enterprise app?

Comment: @Farshid I suspect I know what you are talking about. Enterprise software often pales in comparison to the best publicly available web-based software or web sites when comparing: visual design, interaction design, animation, attention to detail, and overall awesomeness. There are many reasons for the diminished state of enterprise software. I agree with JonW. Asking for examples isn't a question. Consider focusing your request. Ask a question about one interaction in one part of your enterprise software.

Comment: Dear User1757...,  What I'm looking for is inspiration for app layout and items arrangment and application theming for serious corporate scenarios that offer sth more than what is popular currently.

Comment: 'asking for inspiration' simply isn't a very answerable question here on StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

Look at applications that have an awesome UX.  That is what really counts.  As long at the design isn't terrible, it will be the UX that determines whether your customers love or hate you.

**Good design gets out of the way and lets people get the job done**.  If they never notice the design, you've done a good job.

Comment: Sir, I'm asking for a showcase of  applications that have an awesome UX! that is my question!

Comment: We are answering your question with the information you _really_ need. Simply looking at sites that _look_ professional doesn't mean they are. It might not help you, in fact it could even hurt. Focus more on how it should work functionally.

Comment: @johngb, I have to say I don't believe that UX and design are seperate. I believe visual design is part of what we could define as a "user experience", although maybe not the field of UX and what we do as professionals (strictly). The design can not be seperated in my mind from the experience a user has on a site (that site's user experience).

Comment: @JeroenEijkhof My way of looking at it: If the design serves a purpose, then it is UX. If it's just there for the sake of design, then it's design. Too many sites have good artistic design, but horrible UX.

Answer (score 0):

I've found these templates good design inspiration for enterprise apps in many cases. http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-templates

However UX is something that is unique to the application you develop. We can only inherit good features from others.